# What's the purpose of 'New documents based on this template', if you don't need it to create templates?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

Word 2019's Normal.dotm has no coloured styles. So I coloured, and thereby changed, multiple styles of my current .docx. I fancy them to appear by default on future .docx.

[image]

1. I'd save my current document as a (Macro-enabled) Template, correct?

[image]

2. Please see the red arrow. [Suzanne S. Barnhill](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/c7cd283d-2d25-4ebc-9c90-b1fc24a3e429) counsels that 'New documents based on this template' needn't be ticked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### So I coloured, and thereby changed, multiple styles of my current .docx

> I fancy them to appear by default on future .docx.

That won't work, because your current docx file is a normal document not a template.

Suzanne's comment says "if you have the **template** open", so she is referring to a file in the templates directory.

> The default location of the User Templates Folder remains C:\Users\ user name \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates. The User Templates folder will still contain the Normal.dotm template. The location of that folder can be modified (or discovered) using File -> Options -> Advanced -> File Locations.

Source [Templates in Microsoft Word - one of the Tutorials in the Intermediate Users Guide to Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm)